# Can one chant Mantra on behalf of the other person

Tags: mantras

Does it have a benefit or sense (a positive result) to chant Mantra on behalf of someone else in the way that the person in question is receiving result from Mantra chanting?

E.g. someone is ill and having headache and I chant Mantra for him for headache relief: `Om Ksheem Ksheem Ksheem Hah Swaaha`, will it help?

What if that person has no faith in Mantra healing power, will it help?

What if that person is far away from one who is chanting Mantra for him, will it help? Or should both persons be nearby each other?

Can I charge water by chanting Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantra 21 time over the water and give to that person for good heath, will it help (even if that person does not have a faith to Mantra power)?

Thank you!

Comment: Most mantras will have no effect unless chanted by 1. the right person (who is duly initiated by a guru who has almost gained siddhi of that mantra), 2. after following all niyama (rules for clean body & mind) 3.right time & place 4. with right devotion. Other than Bhagavan Nama, chanting these mantras and then losing hope when they don't produce desired effect can result in nastika (atheist) thoughts i.e. mantras are superstition.

Comment: What is siddhi?

Comment: Yes one can and it will help the other person in getting relief. I have a book on Tantras that has mentioned various applications of mantras in curing others' ailments like the one you mentioned in the question. I am not getting enough reference to write an answer. If I get I will write one. @wotesi

Comment: @Rickross Thank you. What is that book on Tantras? What is the name? Is it available in Amazon? If not, is it available in your country? And can you sell me one? Thanks!

Comment: The book name is "Brihat Tantrokta Varidhi' .. It is a compendium type of a book on Tantric applications and mantras. The book is not available on Amazon etc. Its in Bengali too. I bought it from a local book market in Bengal. @wotesi